# How do I listen to URL changes in Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: java, android, chrome-custom-tabs

Im working on an android app, that requires Chrome Custom Tabs (It uses an API that requires this exact package).

I want to know when ChromeTabs gets redirected to a specific URL, but i haven't found anything useful yet.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the ChromeTabs callback method to check the URL, i used deeplinking instead.
I visited this method earlier without any luck, and it seems that because i didn't tell the android to `autoVerify` it didn't list the app as a browser app.

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true"> <--! to tell android 
      that its a browsable app -->
                <data
                    android:host="open"
                    android:scheme="myapp" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: is there anyway to do this with a broadcast receiver?